# 433M/2.4G ISM RF signal coupling on PCB board?

Tags: rf, isolation

thanks for reading my text.

I have an idea:
Use cheap 433M/2.4G transceivers to replace on board digital signal isolator.
Data rate is not a problem.
e.g.  Battery pack cell balancing AFE board.

But RF signal transmission though air is not acceptable.
So how to link them just on board?

STAR connection through （X）pF capacitor in each transceiver's TX pin?
And PCB track should be 50Ohm impedence?

I know little about RF micro-wave.

Advice please. Thanks !

[image]

Comment: If you don't want it to be wireless then why would you replace the isolator?

Comment: The automotive AFE chips I've seen use transformer coupling. If you got creative, you might be able to fabricate the transformers on your pcb - especially since data rate is not that high. There's also opto's which might be an economical solution. Using RF when you really don't need it is making a rod for your own back - especially if you need to do EMC compliance.

Comment: Have you considered optical and how about power supply isolation?

Comment: @Kartman "Using RF when you really don't need it is making a rod for your own back" definitely true, but remember they did it for USB :P https://twitter.com/whitequark/status/1152968571137536002?lang=en

Comment: Thx all.  I found π121U31,  low cost 2 channel 150kbps digital isolater,  which is good for this application.  But I'm still curious about the RF method.  It seems that SOT23-6 foortprint chip LT8988 is very interesting.

Comment: @BeB00 yes,  something like power line communication,  OOK modulated RS-485 transceiver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use coaxial cables, along with attenuators, power combiner/splitters and directional couplers.

You can do it on a PCB, but the solution will be quite big and signals from different transceivers will couple to each other, unless you have a strict RX/TX scheduling.

A better solution would be optical transceivers + fiber, even for short runs inside an instrument.

Comment: Thx all.  I found π121U31,  low cost 2 channel 150kbps digital isolater,  which is good for this application.

Comment: But I'm still curious about the RF method.  It seems that SOT23-6 foortprint chip LT8988 is very interesting.